# C++: Initializing Struct and Setting Function Pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct, initialization

I am trying to initialize a struct with a function pointer, however I am having trouble doing so unless it is done with a global function. The following code works:

```
float tester(float v){
    return 2.0f*v;
}

struct MyClass::Example{
    typedef float(*MyFunc)(float);

    MyFunc NameOfFunc;

    float DoSomething(float a){
        return NameOfFunc(a);
    }
};

struct Example e;
e.MyFunc = tester;
```

My problem is whenever I try to do this with the `tester` function as a function in `MyClass` the code no longer works. In other words, I change the tester function to:

```
float MyClass::tester(float v){
    return 2.0f*v;
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated (including links)! I have tried googling around for the problem but am unsure what to search (I've tried things such as "C++ struct function pointer initialization in class" to no avail)

Comment: You need "c++ pointer to member function". BTW, member function requires context (object to be `this`), so it can't be used the same way as plain functions.

Comment: Since `MyClass::tester` doesn't seem to depend on any non-static members of `MyClass`, maybe you want it to be `static` or just a free function as you had before? (and then this code would work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when you put the function as a member of the class, it will no longer be of the type `float (*)(float)`, but rather, `float (MyClass::*)(float)`.

Look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) to solve these problems.

Example:

```
struct foo {
    float bar(int x, int y) {}
};

// This works
std::function<float(int, int)> func = std::mem_fn(&foo::bar);
```

Comment: I have tried doing what you have suggested to some degree, but have posted a follow up question as this led to more problems

Answer (score 2):

If you want `NameOfFunc` to point to `float MyClass::tester(float v)` then the `Myfunc` declaration must be,

```
typedef float (MyClass::*MyFunc)(float);
```

But then it cannot point to `float tester(float v)`  I don't think you can have one type that can point to either.

Also shouldn't `e.MyFunc = tester;` be `e.NameOfFunc = tester;`?